# how to stop send when input is empty

Tags: javascript, css, forms, input

how i can stop send in form contact from send and show messages to fill input

i use text input and its show in jquery messages like facebox

i use this code

in head

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
    function checkForm(form) {
        var nameCheck = checkName(form.elements['name']),
            mailCheck = checkMail(form.elements['email']),
            phoCheck = checkPho(form.elements['phone']),
            msgCheck = checkMsg(form.elements['msg']);
        return nameCheck && mailCheck && phoCheck && msgCheck;
    }

    function checkName(input) {
        var check = input.value.length >= 30;
        input.style.borderColor = check ? 'black' : 'red';
        return check;
    }

    function checkMail(input) {
        var check = input.value.indexOf('@') >= 0;
        input.style.borderColor = check ? 'black' : 'red';
        return check;
    }

    function checkPho(input) {
        var check = input.value.length >= 5 && input.value !== 'رقم الهاتف';
        input.style.borderColor = check ? 'black' : 'red';
        return check;
}
    function checkMsg(textarea) {
        var check = textarea.value.length >= 500;
        textarea.style.borderColor = check ? 'black' : 'red';
        return check;
    }
    </script>
```

in body

```
<form id="formsend" action="form.php" method="post" onsubmit="return checkForm(this)">
                                    <input name="name" type="text" value="اسمك الكريم" id="name" onblur="if (this.value=='')this.value='اسمك الكريم'" onclick="value=''" onkeyup="checkName(this)" />
                                    <br />
                                    <input name="email" type="text" id="email" value="البريد الالكتروني" onblur="if (this.value=='')this.value='البريد الالكتروني'" onclick="value=''" onkeyup="checkMail(this)" />
                                                        <br />
                                    <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" value="رقم الهاتف" onblur="if (this.value=='')this.value='رقم الهاتف'" onclick="value=''" onkeyup="checkPho(this)" />
                                                        <br />
                                                        <textarea name="msg" cols="39" rows="5" placeholder="نص الرساله" onkeyup="checkMsg(this)" wrap=soft></textarea>
                                                        <br />
                                                        <input type="submit" value="ارسال" id="submit" />
                                    </form>
```

but its work only with email

and i have 4 input (name , email , phone , msg)

can some one tell me what i need to edit or learn me what i can do with it??

Answer (score 0):

You should add checks in your javascript to see if the value of the name, email, phone and msg are equal to the default values. It is probably submitting the form right now because the phone field defaults to رقم الهاتف, which seems to be greater than 5 characters.

EDIT: Here's an example:

```
function checkPho(input) {
    var check = input.value.length >= 5 && input.value !== 'رقم الهاتف';
    input.style.borderColor = check ? 'black' : 'red';
    return check;
}
```

Comment: thx i edit frist post and add full code but submit not work and i dont know why?????